# Tic-Tac-Toe Assignment

Tags: python, arrays

I have to create a function which places the given symbol at the given coordinates on the board. The values of the coordinates on the board are between 0 and 2.The column x comes first, and the row y second.The board consists of the following strings:

- "": empty square
- "X": player 1 symbol
- "O": player 2 symbol

The function should return True if the square was empty and the symbol was successfully placed on the game board. The function should return False if the square was occupied, or if the coordinates weren't valid.

Expected outcome:

```
True
[['', '', 'X'], ['', '', ''], ['', '', '']]
```

My code:

```
def play_turn(game_board: list, x: int, y: int, piece: str):
    row = game_board[y]
    if row[x] == "X" or row[x] == "O" or x >= 3 or y >= 3:
        return False
    elif row[x] == "":
        return True
    row[x] = piece
```

Can someone tell me where I am going wrong.

Comment: You have to update `row[x]` *before* you return `True`. The `return` statement doesn't simply set the return value for when you reach the end of the function; it *is* the end of the function as far as this call is concerned.

Comment: Also, be careful how you create `game_board`; a common mistake with using nested lists to represent a 2D grid is creating a list of multiple references to the same row.

Comment: x and y should never be >=3, but if you have to check, put this condition first, so the other condition don't get evaluated. Otherwise `row[x]` will give an out of range error for x>=3. That's called short circuit evaluation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you also have to check that the coordinates are not lower than 0

```
def play_turn(game_board: list, x: int, y: int, piece: str):
    validCoord = [0, 1, 2]
    if x in validCoord and y in validCoord and game_board[y, x] == "":
        game_board[y, x] = piece  # assign before returning
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Use the debugger to run line by line (for example, in VS Code, you press F10 and only a single line is run). That way you will see that your line `row[x] = piece` is never executed, because you had placed a `return` instruction before.

Comment: Can also do `validCoord = range(3)` for roughly the same effect in a more idiomatic way (IMO).  For a larger board, using `range` will be both less code to type and faster to execute.